# Lipschitz modulus of quadratic loss function

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization

I'm trying to figure out the Lipschitz modulus of quadratic function $\ell(\xi)=\xi^{\top} Q \xi+2 q^{\top} \xi + q_0$ with positive definite $Q$. According to the definition of Lipschitz modulus $\operatorname{Lip}(\ell)=\sup \left\{\|z\|_{*}: \ell^{*}(z)<\infty\right\}$, I need to find the supremum of the dual norm in the domain of the conjugate function of the quadratic, which is $\frac{1}{2}(z-q)^{\top}Q^{-1}(z-q) - q_0$. Since $z$ could be arbitrary vector, the supremum of dual norm is $\infty$. Am I right? Any hint would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quadratic function with positive definite matrix is strongly convex and for that reason, has unbounded Lipschitz modulus. First, notice that since $Q\in\mathbb{S}_{++}^n\Rightarrow \lambda_{\min}(Q)\geq m>0$, hence your quadratic function is strongly convex. Since it is $\sigma=\lambda_{\min}(Q)$ - strongly-convex, it implies that
$$ f(\mathbf{y})- f(\mathbf{x})\geq \nabla f(\mathbf{x})^T(\mathbf{y}-\mathbf{x})+\frac{\sigma}{2}\|\mathbf{y}-\mathbf{x}\|^2\overset{\textbf{C.S.}}{\geq}\|\mathbf{y}-\mathbf{x}\|(\frac{\sigma}{2}\|\mathbf{y}-\mathbf{x}\|-\|\nabla f(\mathbf{x})\|) $$
where the RHS goes to infinity since the coercive function $\|x-y\|\to\infty$ . This means that $|f(\mathbf{x})- f(\mathbf{y})|$ is unbounded, as you correctly suspected.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The explanation of strongly convex and unbounded is super clear. I am still wondering what is the relation between the unbounded |f(y) - f(x)| and Lipschitz modulus. More specifically, could you please also explain the meaning of Lipschitz modulus? or any recommended book/paper/note about it would be appreciated.

Comment: @zzgsam Lipschitz modulus means if we can bound the difference in function values of two points using the distance between these points. Since the difference in function values is related to the derivative (which is the difference between two infinitely close points), Lipschitz modulus. It can be interpreted as if the function value does change "too drastically". I suggest starting with Wikipedia [Lipschitz continuity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lipschitz_continuity) to get a good explanation. You can then use the references there if you'd like to educate yourself more

Comment: Many thanks for your answers. It is clear and intuitive. :)